# Putting Serializable Classes into SQL?

Tags: android, sqlite, serializable

Here's the situation.  I have a bunch of objects that implement `Serializable` that I want to store in a SQL database.  I have two questions

1. Is there a way to serialize the object directly into the database
2. Is that the best way to do it or should I

   2. Write the object out to a formatting `String` and put it in the database that way and then parse it back out
   3. Write each member to the database with a field that is unique to each object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the objects directly using db4o:

http://www.db4o.com/Android/default.aspx

Comment: This is a very cool project!  I spent the whole evening playing with it and it works well, but it's just too slow for mobile apps!

Answer (score 1):

Its generally not a good idea to try and put any sort of object (serialized/deliminated) in your SQL because modifying them is always a bitch.

It sounds like you're on the right track with idea 2.  Is this a one-to-many situation? (because then a xref would obviously be the right answer) or even a foreign key would be better.  cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd still have a table per class + simplistic DAO.
If you absolutely want to do it wrong :), then serialize to JSON and persist the resulting string.